# AngularJS dynamic form field with adding required attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to validate some form fields which are given to me from a backend. I want to be able to add the required attribute if that field name needs that attribute. Here is what I have html side:

```
      <div class="form-group">

        <!-- ************** ADDITIONAL DYNAMIC FIELDS ******** -->

             <div ng-repeat="field in assetFields" ng-cloak>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                     <input type="@{{field.element_type}}" name="@{{field.property}}" class="form-control input-lg" value="" id="@{{field.property}}">
                </div>
      </div>
```

Here is Angularjs side of it:

```
$http.get('/getAssetFeilds/'+$scope.assetType).success(function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.assetFields = data;

                 //loop through the array of json objects
                angular.forEach(data, function(input, key){
                    //get the type of element
                    if(input.element_type == 'text'){
                        //loop through input validations 
                        angular.forEach(input.validations, function(value, key){
                            //check if this input type field is required
                            if(value == 'required'){
                                console.log("#"+input.property);
                                //find the element id value and add required attribute
                                angular.element("#"+input.property).attr('required', 'required');
                            }

                        });
                    }
                });

            });
```

However,its not adding the attribute when I do inspect element. what could be the reason for this not working? which I thought would have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the purpose of the '@' in the attributes?

```
id="@{{field.property}}"
```

Currently the id being set for the elements has the '@' preceding the id name however you are looking for `"#" + input.property` and adding the '@' symbol there, `"#@" + input.property` will give you an `invalid` error.

You will also need to wrap the adding of the `required` attribute in a `$timeout` to make sure the DOM element is rendered first.

```
$timeout(function() {
    angular.element("#" + input.property).attr('required', 'required');
});
```

Here is a [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/CXl2Rc166VNTGFvrzg0L?p=preview) of it working.

Comment: The purpose of the '@' is that i am using laravel php framework which uses the '{{}}' for its blade template.

Comment: Ok, then I'm assuming that you have the `@{{` set up using the `$interpolateProvider` to use that for the Angular bindings, correct? I updated the plnk to reflect that assuming that is what you meant. Try wrapping the adding of the `required` attribute in a `$timeout` in your code and see if that works.